# Combining multiple ints in c

Tags: c

I have three ints.
Fx:
`2012`
`11`
`21`

I want to convert them into a single int `20121121`

Can this be done?
I have tried messing around with `atoi()` without results.

Comment: Are you trying to represent a date? If so, that's very much the wrong way to do it.

Comment: Multiply the first one by `10 ** length of second int`, add second int, multiply result by `10 ** length of third int`, add third int... or `sprintf("%d%d%d")` them together and `atoi` the result. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Yes it is to represent dates. So if i fx had if(20121121 > 20121120) printf("Yes. It is later");

Comment: @Razcou: you can do the comparison without packing into a single int

Comment: @Andrey How? Using a lot of if statements?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, to answer directly the question that you asked, you would do it like this:

```
int combined = year*10000 + month*100 + day;
```

But your approach is quite possibly not the best solution to your actual problem.

Comment: Well, for example for debug logging purposes, or for creating (parts of) unique ID numbers, storing date and time in a number has advantages (space-efficient, monotonically increasing, yet human-readable when normally printed).

Answer (score 4):

If your problem is to compare dates, you can achieve that without packing into a single int.

```
struct Date
{
  int day;
  int month;
  int year;
};

int Compare(const struct Date* d1, const struct Date* d2)
{
  if (d1->year < d2->year) return -1;
  if (d1->year > d2->year) return 1;

  if (d1->month < d2->month) return -1;
  if (d1->month > d2->month) return 1;

  if (d1->day < d2->day) return -1;
  if (d1->day > d2->day) return 1;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is probably a good solution to the underlying problem, but it doesn't answer the question that was asked. Anyway, +1.

Comment: This is a lot heavier-weight than the original approach, and I don't see any real advantages to it unless you want to support hundreds of thousands of years into the future...

Answer (score 3):

An easy way uses the string format to do this.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

snprintf(buffer, sizeof buffer, "%04d%02d%02d", year, month, day);
int result = atoi(buffer);
```

It is not efficient, but could be robust.

Comment: Considering the intended use that has been clarified by the OP (date comparison), `%04d%02d%02d` would work better.